# Dynamically update web reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, web-services

I have developed a .net webservice that runs in my machines IIS at the address –

```
http://localhost/backEnd/service1.asmx
```

Where ‘backEnd’ is the name of the web service.

I also have a WPF desktop application that has that web service address as its reference.

Without recompiling the code is there a way I could deploy this onto client servers that do not use ‘localhost’?

Like a way to dynamically update the service reference?

Comment: Is the web service installed on each of clients servers? Or is the web service held on your servers and the client application calls it?

Comment: It would be on the clients servers.